# Is there any function compulte the count of the macd histgoram line under the zero line between two indexs?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have known the index of two top, is there any way to compute count of the macd histgoram line under the zero line between two indexs?

[image]

I have searched the built-in functions but nothing found. I want a function like filter in js. e.g. `array.filter(value=> value < 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `bar_index` of the last bar that was above or equal to `0` using:

```
previousBar = ta.valuewhen(hist >=0, bar_index, 0)    // hist is the histogram bar variable in this case
```

Then calculate the difference between current bar and `previousBar` only if `hist < 0`:

```
numberOfHistBarsBelowZero = hist < 0 ? bar_index - previousBar : na
plot(numberOfHistBarsBelowZero)
```

**EDIT**

Following some clarifications, if you know the difference between the bars and you want to get the number of bars below 0 between those bars, you can use:

```
math.sum(hist < 0 ? 1 : 0, differenceBetweenBars)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I thought about your answer, when the script executing on the bar below the zero,it can get the number of histbar below the zero through the ”bar_index - previousBar“, but when the script going on execute on the bar above zero, it not work.

Comment: When the script executing on the position of the second red circle in the image,i want to get the number of hist bars between the two red circle.

Comment: If you know the difference between the two bars (if I understood you correctly, you do know), then you can use `math.sum(hist < 0 ? 1 : 0, differenceBetweenBars)`. this will return the sum of the bars that is lower than `0` between in the length that is equal to the total bars between conditions. If this is what you're looking for, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I have tried math.sum(hist < 0 ? 1 : 0, differenceBetweenBars), it worked!
This is what i want, thank you!